# LibreOffice Calc: return regex capturing parentheses

Tags: regex, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to get the site name from a URL in LibreOffice Calc. Currently, I have this formula

```
=REGEX("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/..." , "://(.+)/")
```

It outputs `://stackoverflow.com/`. I want it to output `stackoverflow.com` but I don't understand how to make it return the capturing parentheses content.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the Google-Sheets RE2 regex functions, LibreCalc provides ICU based functionality. Therefor you could try:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=REGEX("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...";"(?<=://)[^/]+")
```

- `(?<=://)` - A positive lookbehind to assert position is preceded by literally '://'.
- `[^/]+` - A negated character class to find 1+ characters other than forward slash.

---

A more convulated way would be to replace the input with a 1st capture group:

```
=REGEX("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...";"^.*://([^/]+).*$";"$1")
```